# How to get the correct time to display in iCal or Calendar app?

Tags: calendar

After moving from one time zone to another, I found myself very frustrated by one issue: even when setting events in my new time zone, all events were displayed in the calendar with the corresponding time in my old time zone, sometimes even shifting them to the previous day because of the 9 hour difference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue. Note the problem was only with my iCloud calendars, as I eventually realized. In any case, I needed to do two things:

1. Check on support for time zones in iCal (that was actually already checked before, and that contributed to the confusion)
2. Login to iCloud.com and change the preferred timezone in the settings (which you can access by clicking on your user name in the top right). Make sure to select the closest city, not just one in your time zone, to avoid later discrepancies from differences in daylight savings; this setting can only be changed on the web site, not in the Calendar.app or system prefs, as far as I can tell

Even after the above was done, I still had the issue in Calendar.app (but no problem anymore in the calendar web interface). It turned out one more little thing needed to be done, which looks more like a bug from Apple:

.    3. Switch off support for time zone, then on again :-)